# How I can define Ln in exp4j compiler java

Tags: android, calculator

I am making android Calculator so I want to define Ln (2.303*Math.log10(number))in exp4j compiler : http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/

but I don't want to put the number manually all the operations are stored in String result 
So I want to tell the compiler when you see Ln do this operation (2.303*Math.log10(number))

```
String txt = txt_Screen.getText().toString();


    try {
        // Calculate the result and display
       // if(txt.contains("ln")) {
         //   txt.replace("ln",)
        Expression expression = new ExpressionBuilder(txt).build();
        double result = expression.evaluate();
        if ((result == Math.floor(result)) && !Double.isInfinite(result)) {


            result_Screen.setText((int) result + "");
        }else
            result_Screen.setText(result+"");


       // double result = expression.evaluate();



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        txt_Screen.setText("Syntax Error");

    }
```

Comment: Why would you use a rough approximation instead of [Math.log](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-)?

Comment: Log is different than Ln

Comment: Math.log is the natural logarithm. What do you claim Ln is?

Comment: @rici I put the function for Ln (2.303*log10(number))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String txt = txt_Screen.getText().toString();


try {
    // Calculate the result and display
   // if(txt.contains("ln")) {
     //   txt.replace("ln",)

 **Function ln = new Function("ln", 1) {
 @Override
 public double apply(double... args) {
    return 2.303*Math.log10(args[0]);
 }
 };**
    Expression expression = new 
ExpressionBuilder(txt).**function(ln)**.build();
    double result = expression.evaluate();
    if ((result == Math.floor(result)) && !Double.isInfinite(result)) {


        result_Screen.setText((int) result + "");
    }else
        result_Screen.setText(result+"");


   // double result = expression.evaluate();



} catch (Exception ex) {
    txt_Screen.setText("Syntax Error");

}
```